# Symbolic link not working in Laravel and image not loading

Tags: laravel

My problem is that when I upload the archim with my site to the hosting and then unpack it there, I lose the symbolic link and the images stop working. How can this be fixed? Everything is fine on the local computer, and I use `php artisan storage:link`, but there is no terminal on the hosting.

Comment: Are you on cPanel?

Comment: no, DirectAdmin

Comment: I answered your question. It will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no `ssh`/`terminal`  access, then create symbolic link with `Route`,  run it once  & delete it.

**route/web.php**  :

```
Route::get('/sym', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have ssh access to the hosting, execute the command.

If you don't have ssh access, like basic hosting with cpanel, you need to configure a cronjob to execute the command. Example:

`* * * * * /path/to/php /home/path/to/project/php artisan storage:link`